# How to add current sources in S-domain?

Tags: circuit-analysis, frequency-domain

I am reading my circuits analysis text book, "Electric circuits 11e", and I came across the following problem. The text book converts a circuit from time domain to frequency domain and ends up with a mixture of current sources in V-s and A-s units. The text then adds the 3 sources together as if they are of the same unit. I get how they transformed the circuit but the addition of the current sources is not making any sense for me. [image: Time domain circuit]

[image: S-domain circuit]

Comment: I don't see how a current source can have units of volts, even volts*sec working in the s domain. Does the text explain this?

Comment: @Fred the idea is if you have a capacitor with an initial current, the current I in the s-domain can be described as I(s)=s*V(s)*C-C*Vinitial. In this case, Vinitial is 50V. The result of the equation is I(s) in V-s. Doing a similar process for the inductor gives a current in A-s.

Comment: Could you properly cite the book please? (Title, Authors, Edition, Year, Publisher.)

Comment: Yeah but the question was how to add two current sources. In the figure the "current" source associated with the inductor has units in V-s. Where I come from we can't add things that have different units.

Comment: The instant the switch is open, the reactive devices are charged so with a transient the voltages and currents take on other values, quickly reaching a new stable state. The second figure takes this fact into account.

Answer (score 4):

These additional current sources that you see are based on initial conditions.

[image]

Source of picture: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:S-Domain_circuit_equivalents.svg

Notice that \$I_0\$ and \$V_0\$ are the current and voltage at \$t=0\$. Why an extra source appears is due to the properties of a Laplace Transform of a derivative. Example:
$$
V = L \frac{dI}{dt} \mapsto V = L(sI-I_0)
$$
Recall: the Laplace Transform of \$\frac{df(t)}{dt}\$ is \$sF(s) - f(0^-)\$.